# How to keep a label in a table view cell from moving out of the screen bounds?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, editing, autoresize

When using a prototype cell of the predefined type "Right Detail" the corresponding table view looks like this:

[image: Right Detail Table View Cell]

and when switching to editing mode it looks like this:

[image: Right Detail Table View Cell in Editing Mode]

As you can see the right detail text label (with text "OVERLAPPING") remains at its original position even though the text label (with text "Title Label") gets shifted to the right in order to make room for the red delete icon.

---

I want to achieve the same behavior with a custom table view cell. However, the detail text label always shifts to the right and out of the screen bounds - whatever I do.

This is my custom cell:

[image: Custom Table View Cell]

and this is how it looks in editing mode:

[image: Custom Table View Cell in Editing Mode]

From my understanding the label should stick to the right when I set the appropriate auto layout constraint:

[image: Auto layout constraint]

It doesn't. Obviously the label's superview (i.e. the cell's `contentView`) is not scaled but simply shifted to the right.

How can I change this and achieve the "Right Detail" behavior in my custom cell?